# Receiving error when trying to insert a Customer

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am attempting to create a customer using the QuickBooks .NET REST API v2 Library.  In calling the Add() method of the dataservice object to submit the request, I get an error message that I don't understand:

```
"EntityManager must be access within a transaction"
```

Googling the error message turns up a few hits with respect to Java, but none look like they really address the issue, nor have I found any documentation in the Intuit-Partner-Platform documentation regarding the message.

```
using Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd;

            OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, Constants.APP_TOKEN, realmID, IntuitServicesType.QBD);
            DataServices dataServices = new DataServices(context);


            var writeCust = new Customer()
            {
                Name = "Carlos Verdona",
                TypeOf = partyType.Person,
                Address = new PhysicalAddress[]
                {
                    new PhysicalAddress()
                        {
                            Line1 = "217 Tarboro Highway",
                            Line2 = "Apt. D",
                            City = "Langleyville",
                            CountrySubDivisionCode = "NC",
                            PostalCode = "55712",
                            Tag = new string[]{"Billing"}
                        }
                },
                Phone = new TelephoneNumber[]
                {
                    new TelephoneNumber()
                    {
                        DeviceType = "Work",
                        FreeFormNumber = "111-345-3456"
                    },
                    new TelephoneNumber()
                    {
                        DeviceType = "Mobile",
                        FreeFormNumber = "111-345-3457"
                    }
                },
                WebSite = new WebSiteAddress[]
                {
                    new WebSiteAddress()
                    {
                        URI = "http://www.HorseBrains.com"
                    }
                },
                Email = new EmailAddress[]
                {
                    new EmailAddress()
                    {
                        Address = "CVerdona@HorseBrains.com"
                    }
                },
                GivenName = "",
                MiddleName = "",
                FamilyName = "",
                DBAName = "",
                ShowAs = "Carlos Verdona",
                //CustomField = new CustomField[]
                //{
                //    new BooleanTypeCustomField()
                //    {
                //        DefinitionId =  "Bill With Parent",
                //        Value = true
                //    },
                //    new StringTypeCustomField()
                //    {
                //        DefinitionId = "Preferred Delivery Method",
                //        Value = "PRINT"
                //    }

                //},
                SalesTermId = new IdType() {idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "8" },

            };

            //Create Customer
            Customer output = dataServices.Add(writeCust);
```

Thanks for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Please try Apiexploer tool to create the customer object by directly calling the 'Create customer' endpoint.
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiName=V2QBO

You can refer the following docs API and .Net devkit links too.

API Docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/customer

Synchronous call doc ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0299_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

Asyn call doc ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0300_asynchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

Hope these will be useful

can you check using plain setters of Customer entity.

Comment: Hi Manas,  I don't understand what you mean by "can you check using plain setters of Customer entity"

Comment: I meant to say ..
Customer c = new Customer();
c.setName("").. I think this approach is more readable(I think)
and before constructing object.. it is better to test the object using apiexplorer. it helps to detect XML specific errors or syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are referencing using Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd; and therefore customer object is created for QBD. Then in the last few lines, you pass id domain as QBO:
SalesTermId = new IdType() {idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "8" },

Please correct this.
Use the correct library Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo

Comment: There's one more problem, you are passing string type as Tag value for address, whereas it reuqires an enum of PhysicalAddresslabelType.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching a sample code for your reference:[image]